# Devel's dpm needs two refreshes to display message from (pre)process

Tags: 7, debugging, theming

I use `Zen` and have copy/pasted the `STARTERKIT` to my `foo` template.
`Devel` is enabled with the "Rebuild the theme registry on every page load" setting on.

In my completely empty `template.php` I type in the following and save:

```
function foo_process_node(&$variables, $hook) {
    dpm('test');
}
```

I then do `drush cc all` and refresh page. The message is not shown. If I refresh again the message shows.

If I change `test` to `foobar` on the 1st refresh I get the old `test` and on the second I get `foobar`.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Note that this lagging behavior is the same for `preprocess` and `process` but not there if I print the message from the `foo_page_alter(&$page)` function.

Comment: Hm. Maybe it's not a `Devel` issue but a more generic one because I'm getting the exact same behavior for error messages. I'm seeing the error message of the previous page load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common issue people encounter when themeing Drupal (it used to drive me crazy).

In basic terms what's happening is that the messages held in the `$_SESSION` super global have already been committed to the page by the time the template file containing your call to `dpm()` is invoked.

This means that the messages are added to the `$_SESSION` but aren't dumped out to the messages area until the next page...as `$messages` has already been set up for/printed in page.tpl.php.

The normal way to get around this is to invoke the `dpm()` at an earlier stage of the process, like in `hook_page_alter()` as you mention, or `hook_node_view()`, etc.

Also I think if you implement your preprocess hook at the module level, rather than the theme level, that your calls to `dpm()` will happen in time for the messages to be displayed in that particular page request.

Answer (score 3):

This has been an issue for me as well. 
Another workaround for this by using kpr($your_variable), which is also a function in devel and that seems to display the output on the first page load.

Comment: works for me...

Answer (score 0):

`dsm` method is called to `dpm` method. so we need to call `dpm`.

in `dpm` -- p indicate the `print_r()`.

`dpm` is just show the array and object as print_r only difference is it show it in error display block.
because internally it use `drupal_set_message`.